# I am experiencing difficulties with creating or editing records in my ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am facing an issue in my ASP.NET Core MVC application where I am unable to create or edit records. Initially, these operations were functioning correctly. However, after introducing some modifications to the Meal model, the create and edit functionalities are no longer working as expected.

Here's my `Meal` model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Caloracker1.Models
{
    public class Meal
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public double? TotalCalorie { get; set; }
        public double? Amount { get; set; }
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public double? Carbonhydrate { get; set; }
        public double? Protein { get; set; }
        public double? Fat { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My `MealController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Caloracker1.Data;
using Caloracker1.Models;

namespace Caloracker1.Views
{
    public class MealsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Caloracker1Context _context;

        public MealsController(Caloracker1Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Meals
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Meal.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Meals/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var meal = await _context.Meal
                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
 
            if (meal == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(meal);
        }

        // GET: Meals/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Meals/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,TotalCalorie,Amount,ImageUrl,Description,Carbonhydrate,Protein,Fat")] Meal meal)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(meal);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(meal);
        }

        // GET: Meals/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var meal = await _context.Meal.FindAsync(id);

            if (meal == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(meal);
        }

        // POST: Meals/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,TotalCalorie,Amount,ImageUrl,Description,Carbonhydrate,Protein,Fat")] Meal meal)
        {
            if (id != meal.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(meal);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!MealExists(meal.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(meal);
        }

        // GET: Meals/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var meal = await _context.Meal
                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (meal == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(meal);
        }

        // POST: Meals/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var meal = await _context.Meal.FindAsync(id);

            if (meal != null)
            {
                _context.Meal.Remove(meal);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool MealExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Meal.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

And my view for create and edit

CREATE

```
@model Caloracker1.Models.Meal

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Meal</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TotalCalorie" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="TotalCalorie" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TotalCalorie" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Amount" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ImageUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ImageUrl" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ImageUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Carbonhydrate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Carbonhydrate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Carbonhydrate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Protein" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Protein" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Protein" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Fat" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Fat" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Fat" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
@model Caloracker1.Models.Meal

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Meal</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TotalCalorie" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="TotalCalorie" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TotalCalorie" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Amount" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ImageUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ImageUrl" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ImageUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Carbonhydrate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Carbonhydrate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Carbonhydrate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Protein" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Protein" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Protein" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Fat" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Fat" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Fat" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have provided the relevant sections of the `MealsController` and the associated views for Create and Edit operations.

Despite these changes, the create and edit operations are not working as expected. Any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should provide more info on what is not working. API action is not hit? Get any exception? Also, you should provide only the code that is faced the issue instead of posting everything here.

Comment: What modifications did you make to the model? After you modified the model, did you receive any error messages? What exactly do you mean by no longer working? Is the meal model you provided before modification?

Answer (score 0):

> after introducing some modifications to the Meal model, the create and edit functionalities are no longer working as expected.

Please note that each time the model changes, it gets out of sync with the database.

You could do migrations and apply updates to your database with following steps:

PM> add-migration newupdates

PM> update-database

For more information about EF Core Migrations, please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs

Comment: I fixed my problem. The problem was caused by a version conflict of packages. Thanks for your answer.